Linux from Scratch: custom GUI
If I follow the Linux From Scratch (LFS) manual, how do I go about setting up my own graphical user interface, that is, the "desktop environment"?
I'd like to do it by using an HTML solution such as the Sciter engine. But I have the following questions:

After setting up LFS, how do I link my own desktop environment (e.g. Sciter Hello World)?
If I can really use Sciter to build my desktop environment, then how can I customise the window manager details (icons, font, appearance of buttons, checkboxes etc.)?

I was pretending to use HTML because it supports rich graphics and easing transitions out of the  box.
I need an own desktop environment because:

I need both windowed and Metro fullscreen apps.
A fullscreen start menu as in Metro.
I need touch gestures around the screen, such as for the "system status" (what time is it,  battery etc.), pushing background apps, pushing current app, and splitting screen (and, for Metro fullscreen apps, showing the minimize-maximize-close chrome).


sciter is just a HTML engine; you can't build a desktop environment from that, it assumes a desktop environment already there to manage its windows, handle notifications and integrate different application. If I may say, applications built atop of sciter and similar engines tend to be the worst-integrating components in modern desktop environments; always feels like someone was following their own UI paradigms instead of using the system-supplied components. And that's inherent – these things are effectively browsers with no intention to integrate with other components well.

none of the things you mention as reason for having your own desktop environment actually necessitate your own desktop environment. This all just sounds like a relatively limited GNOME shell plugin (javascript), or a kwin/KDE environment (many languages), or some plugin for another existing desktop environment. Sciter would still not be useful for any of these!

@MarcusMüller So it's enough to fork Linux Mint for that? I've looked at their Cinnamon's JavaScript UI sources but found the coding quite complex (specially the OS itself had applet .js files in /usr/share/)

why would you fork a distro to write a plugin? That's like "I want to add a air refreshener to my car, I should copy a Peugeot factory!"

You mention "Metro fullscreen apps"? Are you talking about that Metro thing from Windows, now called UWP, I think? AFAIK there's still no way to run them on Linux.
